# Database->Servlet->jsp

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve all the mysql database table records in servlet and display all the rows through jsp. It is also confusing that whether I should use `String[]` array or I should create and use another class and create object for that class. As of now, I am done with considering `String[]` array, but in display it is showing only first record of the table database.

I expect answer to my question for my question as earlier as possible

Comment: Please read the [faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking any question

Comment: Provide your servlet and JSP code so that it will be known what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done jsp for years but the following has worked for me in the past

```
String Query = "Select fieldname1, fieldname2, fieldname3 from table";

ResultSet SQLResult = SQLStatement.executeQuery(Query);
while(SQLResult.next())
{
    field1 = SQLResult.getString("fieldname1");
    field2 = SQLResult.getString("fieldname2");
    field3 = SQLResult.getString("fieldname3");

    out.println(field1 + "," + field2 + "," + field3);
}
```